# When button clicked change textbox value in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My code is shown below:

```
document.getElementById('Login').onClick=LogIn;
function LogIn(){
document.getElementById('UserName').value='test';
document.getElementById('Password').value='test2';
 }
```

When i click button i got exception

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null

My html code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=utf8>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish>
<script src="doktormdcore.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> UserName:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="UserName" size="20" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="password" id="Password" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Enter" id="Login"  /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What i must supposed to do. I dont want to use jquery.

Comment: It can't find your element of ID `Login`, post your HTML markup for your button please. Here's a working fiddle of your code, and as the answer below also suggests, it's `onclick` not `onClick` : http://jsfiddle.net/TuKcK/

Comment: Can you post the full context of where your code is placed.

Comment: Updated post.  Added html code.

Comment: Is this a chrome-extension?  The fiddle that @tymeJV posted assumes that the code is executed `onload` which is obviously the solution to the problem if your code is just included in the page and is not a chrome extension.  If your code is in `doktormdcore.js`, the answer is you need to defer execution until the `load` or `DOM ready` event since `Login` won't exist when your code is executed as is.

Comment: How can i check if dom ready or not in pure javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `onClick` to `onclick`.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

**Edit**

I am still not sure if your code is an extension or not but here is how you could ensure that the page is fully loaded if you attach your code to the `onload` event.

```
  function LogIn(){
    document.getElementById('UserName').value='test';
    document.getElementById('Password').value='test2';
  }
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('Login').onclick=LogIn;
  }
```

Comment: Tried. But still same exception.